# Running nested for loops without repeating variables?

Tags: performance, for-loop, nested-loops

Is there an efficient way to run nested for loops, avoiding any of the counters having the same value. Obviously, I could run some if statements, as below, but is there a more efficient way?

```
for i = 1 to 20:
    for j = 1 to 20:
        if (i == j):
            continue
        else:            
            for k = 1 to 20:
                if (i == k) or (j == k):
                    continue
                else:
                    do something useful with these different numbers
```

EDIT: The variables are not interchangeable, so [2, 1, 0] is different to [0, 1, 2]. The "do something useful" will be about 6 numerical checks on the numbers, involving adding, squaring, and square rooting them.

Thanks, and sorry about the possibly unusual pseudocode (and the constant editing).

Comment: You can get rid of the else sections by inverting the logic of the if ( `i!=j` and `(i!-k) and (j!=k)`  respectively) but that's not really efficiency but readability.

Comment: The nesting of your loops can impact performance (due to effects on branch prediction and memory locality), but this is dependent on what is inside of "do something useful with these different numbers."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like the most efficient way you can do it. What's wrong with how you have it?

I'm just going to ignore the part where I can't think of any reason to ever need to do this.... so if you have a specific case please share? Unless your trying to compare an item to all other items in a list that isn't itself I guess?

which could be done as

```
list = {1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4} \\where list[0] will return 1, and list.size() will return 8
for(int i = 0; i < list.size()-1; i++){
    for(int j = i + 1; j < list.size(); j++){
        System.out.println(list[i] + "," + list[j]);
    }
}
```

That way you dont repeat comparisons between things you have already compared.

For three nests

```
list = {1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4} \\where list[0] will return 1, and list.size() will return 8
for(int i = 0; i < list.size()-2; i++){
    for(int j = i + 1; j < list.size()-1; j++){
        for(int k = j + 1; j < list.size(); k++){
            System.out.println(list[i] + "," + list[j] + "," + list[k]);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a mathematical problem, where none of the three variables are allowed to be the same, and I'm brute forcing it, so I'm trying to make everything as efficient as possible.

Comment: There are other optimisations I'll use, but I thought that putting them in the original question would confuse matters, I didn't want any help with them. The problem is: http://unsolvedproblems.org/index_files/MagicSquare.htm , I know I won't get anywhere with an unsolved problem like that, it's more for fun.

Comment: okay well then my answer is more efficient then what you started with, as long as i, j, and k are all interchangeable. replace list.size() with the end point of your search.

My solution is better because it cuts out half of the calculations, not repeating tests that where already tried.

Comment: in your magic square case, you would want to create multipule test cases in my program, or a single test case in yours. They would average the same number of computations in the long run though

Comment: i, j and k are not interchangeable, I'm afraid. However, your posts have brought something else to my attention, which I'll probably make a new question for, if I can't work out something myself. So thank you. Oh, and the way I'm doing it is a bit more developed than using 9 for loops, one for each number in the square, in case that's relevant.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you can possibly save efficiency on here is your looping logic. Assuming you implement it correctly, there are always going to be 20*19*18 operations to do.

You won't be able to find a solution with the limited detail you have given. What is the 'something useful'?

If it turns out that for that operation, the individual values of i, j, and k do not matter, just the combination of 3 numbers, then yes you can make significant efficiency savings. With your current set up, you will pass in the (i,j,k) values (1, 2, 3) (1,3,2) (2,1,3) (2,3,1) etc...

So if you are looking for combinations, not permutations, you can modify it to reduce effort by a fact of 6 quite easily, by starting j one bigger than i, and k one bigger than j in each internal loop.

Comment: I've edited the question to include this, which I should have done initially. Thanks.